# How can i use callback and update class variable

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to update a class variable on interrupt callback from a physical switch

```
### .py

class Mode1(Screen):

    var= 0

    def my_callback(channel,self):
        self.var+=20

    gpio.add_event_detect(17, gpio.RAISING, callback=my_callback)
```

**I need to update the variable when a physical button connected via raspberry pi is pressed. The Pressing of Button must be an interrupt/callback**

Comment: it would appear that you for you arguments in the wrong order, try `def my_callback(self, channel):`

Comment: Tried. That didn't work neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating a class variable, do it inside a `classmethod`

```
class Mode1(Screen):
    var = 1
    @classmethod
    def my_callback(cls, channel):
        cls.var += 20
gpio.add_event_detect(17, gpio.RAISING, callback=Mode1.my_callback)
```

Comment: I need to update this var in kivy so I think self is needed. I will edit the question so that you can understand the whole situation